# Linux driver for an emulated SPI device without DT/ACPI info

Tags: cross-platform, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, spi

The vast majority of real SPI devices are platform-specific, and provide some means for automated discovery/enumeration (usually via Device Tree or ACPI). I need to write a kernel module for a dummy SPI device which doesn't have any platform-specific identity, and can be accessed via [spidev](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/spi/spidev.html). I've tried to write the controller driver for it first, but the system won't see it since it doesn't represent any real device (or?).

I've already implemented a dummy I2C device using the i2c-dev driver, but i2c-dev itself provides a discovery mechanism using bus notifier chains, so eventually I was able to add my adapter to the system.

So my question is: what steps should I take to be able to see my dummy SPI device as `/dev/spidevB.C`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a skeleton of a driver that creates a dummy SPI controller with some SPIDEV client devices attached to it. It probably needs more work to emulate the transfers properly in the SPI controller, but it seems to be good enough to make the SPIDEV devices appear in the system.

**fake-spidev.c**

```c
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/spi/spi.h>

struct fake_spi_controller_platform_data {
    u16 num_chipselect;
};

struct fake_spi {
    int todo;   /* placeholder */
};

static struct platform_device *fake_spi_controller_device;

static int fake_spi_controller_probe_pdata(struct platform_device *pdev,
                       struct spi_controller *ctlr)
{
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    struct fake_spi_controller_platform_data *pdata = dev_get_platdata(dev);
    struct fake_spi *fake_spi = spi_controller_get_devdata(ctlr);

    ctlr->num_chipselect =
        pdata && pdata->num_chipselect ? pdata->num_chipselect : 1;
    fake_spi->todo = 42;    /* placeholder */

    return 0;
}

static int fake_spi_transfer_one(struct spi_controller *ctlr,
                 struct spi_device *spi,
                 struct spi_transfer *transfer)
{
    spi_finalize_current_transfer(ctlr);
    return 0;
}

static int fake_spi_controller_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    int rc;
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    struct spi_controller *ctlr;
    struct fake_spi *priv;
    unsigned int cs;
    struct spi_board_info board_info = {
        /* Not sure if there is better way to match the spidev driver */
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,15,0)
        .modalias = "spidev",
#else
        .modalias = "bk4",  /* One of the IDs matched by spidev */
#endif
        .max_speed_hz = 1000000,
        .mode = SPI_MODE_0,
    };

    ctlr = devm_spi_alloc_master(dev, sizeof(*priv));
    if (!ctlr)
        return -ENOMEM;

    rc = fake_spi_controller_probe_pdata(pdev, ctlr);
    if (rc)
        return rc;

    priv = spi_controller_get_devdata(ctlr);

    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, priv);

    ctlr->transfer_one = fake_spi_transfer_one;

    ctlr->mode_bits = SPI_CPOL | SPI_CPHA;

    rc = devm_spi_register_controller(dev, ctlr);
    if (rc) {
        dev_err(dev, "unable to register SPI controller.\n");
        return rc;
    }

    /* Create SPIDEV devices. */
    board_info.bus_num = ctlr->bus_num;
    for (cs = 0; cs < ctlr->num_chipselect; cs++) {
        struct spi_device *spi;

        board_info.chip_select = cs;
        spi = spi_new_device(ctlr, &board_info);
        if (!spi) {
            dev_warn(dev, "failed to create SPI device %u: %s\n",
                 cs, board_info.modalias);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static int fake_spi_controller_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    return 0;
}

static struct platform_driver fake_spi_controller_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "fake-spi-controller",
    },
    .remove = fake_spi_controller_remove,
};

static const struct fake_spi_controller_platform_data fake_spi_pdata = {
    .num_chipselect = 2,
};

static int __init fake_spidev_init(void)
{
    int rc;

    fake_spi_controller_device =
        platform_create_bundle(&fake_spi_controller_driver,
                       fake_spi_controller_probe,
                       NULL, 0,
                       &fake_spi_pdata, sizeof(fake_spi_pdata));
    rc = PTR_ERR_OR_ZERO(fake_spi_controller_device);
    if (rc) {
        goto fail_create_fake_spi_controller_device;
    }
    return 0;

fail_create_fake_spi_controller_device:

    return rc;
}

static void __exit fake_spidev_exit(void)
{
    platform_device_unregister(fake_spi_controller_device);
    platform_driver_unregister(&fake_spi_controller_driver);
}

module_init(fake_spidev_init);
module_exit(fake_spidev_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

**Makefile**

```make
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

obj-m += fake-spidev.o

else

# Default to running kernel's build directory if KDIR not set externally
KDIR ?= "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build"

all:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" modules

install:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" modules_install

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" clean

endif
```

Comment: Nice, but it uses platform data in 21st century

Comment: @0andriy At least I made it optional. :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott I've already come up with my own solution, but thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: @0andriy and what would you suggest in the 21st century?

Comment: @random69579, Device tree or ACPI or other platform description and resource provider.

Comment: @0andriy The question title says "without DT/ACPI info".

Comment: Some questions are smart and some are different.

Comment: @0andriy I presume this question is a smart one since you participate in discussing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own solution :) Unlike Ian's, my driver doesn't pretend to be spidev, but [binds](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/spi/spidev.html) to it.

**my_spi.c**

```c
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/printk.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/slab.h>
    #include <linux/errno.h>
    #include <linux/uaccess.h>
    #include <linux/spi/spi.h>
    
    #include <linux/platform_device.h>
    
    static struct spi_master *master;
    static struct spi_device *spi_dev;
    
    static int myspi_transfer_one(struct spi_controller *ctlr, struct spi_device *spi,
                    struct spi_transfer *transfer)
    {
        pr_info("%s()\n", __func__);
        pr_info(" transfer->len == %u\n", transfer->len);
    
        if (transfer->rx_buf) {
            unsigned char * rx_buf = transfer->rx_buf;
            const unsigned char * tx_buf = transfer->tx_buf;
            int i;
    
            for (i = 0; i < transfer->len; i++)
                rx_buf[i] = ~tx_buf[i];
    
        }
    
        spi_finalize_current_transfer(ctlr);
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    struct spi_board_info chip = {
        .modalias = "my_spi",
    };
    
    static int plat_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
    {
        int err = 0;
    
        pr_info("%s()\n", __func__);
    
        master = spi_alloc_master(&pdev->dev, 0);
    
        if (master == NULL) {
            pr_err("spi_alloc_master failed\n");
            return -ENOMEM;
        }
    
        master->num_chipselect = 1;
    
        master->transfer_one = myspi_transfer_one;
    
        err = spi_register_master(master);
    
        if (err) {
            pr_err("spi_register_master failed\n");
            spi_master_put(master);
            return err;
        }
    
        spi_dev = spi_new_device(master, &chip);
    
        if (!spi_dev)
            /* TODO do we need to do anything else? */
            err = -ENOMEM;
    
        if (err)
            pr_err("spi driver error\n");
        else
            pr_info("spi driver ok\n");
    
        return err;
    }
    
    static int plat_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
    {
        pr_info("%s()\n", __func__);
    
        spi_unregister_master(master);
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    static struct platform_device * plat_device;
    
    
    static struct platform_driver plat_driver = {
        .driver = {
            .name   = "my_platform",
            .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        },
        .probe      = plat_probe,
        .remove     = plat_remove,
    };
    
    static int __init myspi_init(void)
    {
        int err = -ENODEV;
    
        plat_device =  platform_device_register_simple("my_platform",
            PLATFORM_DEVID_NONE, NULL, 0);
    
        if (IS_ERR(plat_device))
            return PTR_ERR(plat_device);
    
        err =  platform_driver_register(&plat_driver);
    
        if (err)
            return err;
    
        if (!err)
            pr_info("spi driver loaded\n");
    
        return err;
    }
    
    static void __exit myspi_exit(void) {
    
        platform_driver_unregister(&plat_driver);
        platform_device_unregister(plat_device);
    
        pr_info("spi driver unloaded\n");
    }
    
    
    module_init(myspi_init);
    module_exit(myspi_exit);
    
    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

**Makefile**

```
obj-m += my_spi.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Usage:

```
# modprobe spidev
# insmod my_spi.ko
# echo spidev > /sys/bus/spi/devices/spi0.0/driver_override
# echo spi0.0 > /sys/bus/spi/drivers/spidev/bind
# ls /dev/spi*
/dev/spidev0.0
```

Testing with [spidev_test](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/spi/spidev_test.c):

```
# ./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev0.0 -v -p "12345"
spi mode: 0x0
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 kHz)
TX | 31 32 33 34 35 __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __  |12345|
RX | CE CD CC CB CA __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __  |.....|
```

Comment: TBF, mine doesn't pretend to be spidev either. (I should have chosen a better name for it.) It just sets the modalias of the SPI devices to bind to spidev. If you did that too, you wouldn't need the driver_override stuff. It's a shame setting modalias to "spidev" stopped working in 5.15. I wonder if there is a better workaround than the one I used?

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm not sure whether they should have banned the word "spidev" from being used as modalias, but I think driver binding is the proper way of doing things like that anyway :)

Comment: It’s not a shame, it’s proper solution — no one should use *spidev* in production.

Comment: @0andriy I have had a situation where the customer needed an uncommitted SPI port (basically, the board has a PCB header for the SPI bus) in the same way as they needed an uncommitted serial port, and have had to resort to "lying" about the device type in the compatible string to map it to the spidev driver. At least have an SPI device type called "generic-spi" or something.