# Virtual serial SPI port WSL2

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, wsl-2, spi, pty

i am using a Python module for a LED strip (APA102), that communicates over my Raspberry Pi's SPI pins. When I execute scripts on my WSL2 locally (since I don't have my Pi always with me), i get an exception when trying to import the `apa102_pi` module with the following traceback:

```
WARNING: GENERIC_X86 is not fully supported. Some features may not work.
WARNING: GENERIC_X86 is not fully supported. Some features may not work.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/apa_env/bin/apa102_server", line 33, in <module>
     sys.exit(load_entry_point('michaelstuffer98.apa102-tcp-server==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'apa102_server')())
   File "/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/apa_env/bin/apa102_server", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
      return next(matches).load()
   File "/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 86, in load
      module = import_module(match.group('module'))
   File "/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/apa_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apa102_tcp_server/led_audio_controller.py", line 3, in <module>
      from apa102_tcp_server.apa_led import LedStrip
   File "/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/apa_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apa102_tcp_server/apa_led.py", line 1, in <module>
      from apa102_pi.driver import apa102
   File "/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/apa_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apa102_pi/driver/apa102.py", line 10, in <module>
      from microcontroller.pin import spiPorts
ImportError: cannot import name 'spiPorts' from 'microcontroller.pin' (/home/michael/.pyenv/versions/3.9.15/envs/apa_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/microcontroller/pin.py)
```

This happens imo because I don't have serial pins available. I already worked with pseudo-terminals before, is it possible to create a workaround with that, or is there another a possibility to create this interface virtually? I actually don't really need the functionality (still would be nice to have that too), but only want to make importing the module work.

Comment: It is possible to create fake SPI controllers using a custom kernel module (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73139063/5264491 ) but actually building and loading kernel modules for WSL2's kernel is tricky. Then you would need to override the platform detection in Adafruit's libraries by setting the `BLINKA_FORCE_BOARD` and `BLINKA_FORCE_CHIP` environment variables. I don't know why you would want to run these scripts anyway since there is nothing to attach the LED strip to.

Comment: @IanAbbott, one may simply buy something like Diolan DLN2 USB-to-SPI (and others) controller and have it available everywhere.